# Hide the login button after logged in and vice versa

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

This is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router:Router) { 
     this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout(){
    debugger;
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    console.log(this.afAuth);
  }

}
```

My html view part of login and log out is here

```
<ul class="list-inline nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

             <li class="list-inline-item" ngIf="!(afAuth.auth| async)"><a (click)="login()" style="color:red;">Login</a></li>
             <li class="list-inline-item" ngIf="(afAuth.auth| async)"><a (click)="logout()" style="color:red;">Logout</a></li>

         </ul>
```

I want to hide login button after logged in, and also when log out i want to show login,But its not working.

The error is

```
ERROR Error: No provider for TemplateRef!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2741)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2610)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3578)
    at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11039)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10895)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10723)
```

Please help me to find the answer

Comment: You're missing the "*" in front of *ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

> "The (*) prefix to ngIf is a critical part of this syntax" [Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#asterisk)

with that being said you are missing all the (*) on every `*ngIf`

```
<ul class="list-inline nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="list-inline-item" *ngIf="!(user | async)"><a (click)="login()" style="color:red;">Login</a></li>
<li class="list-inline-item" *ngIf="(user | async)"><a (click)="logout()" style="color:red;">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: WHEN logged in it hides the login button,but when i click it is not showing the login button again.Why it is showing so?